# How to use .htaccess to redirect while maintaining the original URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-masking

I am trying to use the .htacces file to redirect any files or subfolders in a derectory to one file, while still maintaining the original URL input.

So if a user goes to:

```
https://example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/
or
https://example.com/folder1/folder2/file.php
```

it would redirect them back to:

```
https://example.com/folder1/index.php
```

but the original URL input would not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RewriteRule` . In htaccess in the document root add the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder1/.+$ /folder1/index.php [L]
```

This will redirect `/folder1/foo/bar` to `/folder1/index.php` without changing the url in browser.
The `RewriteCond` above makes sure you don't rewrite `/folder1/index.php` to itself (`/folder1/index.php`) otherwise the rule can cause an infinite loop error.

Comment: This works great.  I removed the folder1 and added to an .htaccess files inside of folder1:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just make :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^https://example.com/folder1/ https://example.com/folder1/index.php
```

> This allows you to redirect from the first url in the pattern  to the
>   second one

Comment: There are an infinite number of possible URLs that could be input, and I want the original URL input to stay in the address bar.

Comment: you mean url that start with https://example.com should be redirected ? is that true ?

Comment: I want anything after example.com/folder1/ to redirect to example.com/folder1/index.php